# Convergence of a real sequence iff $-\infty \lt \liminf_{x\to \infty} a_n = \limsup_{x\to \infty} a_n \lt \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Could someone help me with this exercise? How would I go about this, how would I start?

---

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a real sequence. Show that:

$(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is convergent in $\mathbb R$ if and only if $$-\infty \lt \liminf_{n\to \infty} a_n = \limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n \lt \infty$$

Comment: Do you mean $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Hint: What can you say about the set of subsequent limits of a convergent sequence? Vice - versa?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864822/show-that-the-lim-inf-a-n-lim-sup-a-n-if-and-only-if-lim-a-n-exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that the $\lim \inf a_n = \lim \sup a_n$ if and only if $\lim a_n$ exists.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864822/show-that-the-lim-inf-a-n-lim-sup-a-n-if-and-only-if-lim-a-n-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the definitions:

$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n:=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\sup_{m\geq n}a_m)$$
$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n:=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\inf_{m\geq n}a_m)$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\inf_{m\geq n}a_m)\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\sup_{m\geq n}a_m)$$

Notice that $(\sup_{m\geq n}a_m)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(\inf_{m\geq n}a_m)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ can be seen as subsequences of $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$.

And we know (as  AnotherJohnDoe suggested in the comments) that all the subsequences of a convergent sequence must converge to the same limit (the limit of the original sequence).

So assuming that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \mathbb N} a_n$ exists (is not $\pm\infty$) we must have that
$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \mathbb N} a_n$$

Conversely assume that

$$-\infty<\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n<\infty$$

$$-\infty<\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\inf_{m\geq n}a_m)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\sup_{m\geq n}a_m)<\infty$$

Because $(\inf_{m\geq n}a_m)\leq a_n\leq(\sup_{m\geq n}a_m)$ you just take limits and noticing that the extremes are equal then the sequence must converge.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*:

For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $k_0\in\Bbb N$ such that
$$-\epsilon+\liminf a_n<a_k<\limsup a_n+\epsilon$$
for all $k\ge k_0$.